# How to split string with new line character \n

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print by breaking a line based on character \n (new line). Below is the example:

```
line = "This is list\n 1.Cars\n2.Books\n3.Bikes"
```

I want to print the output as below:

```
This is list:
1.Cars
2.Books
3.Bikes
```

I used code as below:

```
line1 = line.split()
for x in line1:     
    print(x)
```

But its printing each word in different line. How to split the string based on only "\n"

Regards,
Arun Varma

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `split()` specifies the string to use as a delimiter. If you don't give an argument it splits on any whitespace by default.

If you only want to split at newline characters, use

```
line1 = line.split('\n')
```

There's also a method specifically for this:

```
line1 = line.splitlines()
```